# Don't know what this expanding periodic-ish function is

Tags: functions, collatz-conjecture

I plotted a function $c(x)$, which returns $3x + 1$ if $x$ is odd, and $x/2$ if $x$ is even. It's the Collatz conjecture. I get [this](http://www.plotvar.com/line.php?title=&yaxis=&xvalues=&serie1=&values_serie1=0%2C4%2C1%2C10%2C2%2C16%2C3%2C22%2C4%2C28%2C5%2C34%2C6%2C40%2C7%2C46%2C8%2C52%2C9%2C58%2C10%2C64%2C11%2C70%2C12%2C76%2C13%2C82%2C14%2C88%2C15%2C94%2C16%2C100%2C17%2C106%2C18%2C112%2C19%2C118%2C20%2C124%2C21%2C130%2C22%2C136%2C23%2C142%2C24%2C148%2C25%2C154%2C26%2C160%2C27) interesting function. I don't know what it's called, so I can't learn more about it. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: The graph shows the first iteration of the Collatz sequence for a given $x$. It is a piecewise graph with two parts -- $x$ being even, and $x$ being odd -- where both pieces are linear.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "first iteration of the Collatz sequence"?

Comment: It only shows the first step. For example, at $x=3$, the graph plots the point $(3,10)$ because $3$ is odd and $3\times 3 + 1 = 10$. The next point, at $x=4$, is $2$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is made up of two parts:

When $x$ is odd, it is the graph of $f(x) = 3x + 1$.

When $x$ is odd, it is the graph of $f(x) = x/2$.

That's why you get two lines: the first with slope $3$ on top and the second with slope $1/2$ on the bottom.

Note that the lines between the dots should not be there. The domain is only on the integers.